# Form.io dependent dropdown to be filtered from the Resource data

Tags: javascript, formio, form.io

I have a form where I need to select state from dropdown1
these values are loaded from the form.io resource DB (Community DB)

upon state drop down selection, I need to fetch the community names belonging to above state dropdwn selected value

My (Community DB) appears like
[image: image.png]

My state dropdown should display all states from state column
My second dropdown should fetch data from previously selected state and only display the relevant community names

I have tried using

My State data tab shows
[image: image.png]

My Community data tab shows
[image: image.png]

My embedded form is here

```html
<script type="text/javascript">(function a(d, w, u) {var h = d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];var s = d.createElement("script");s.type = "text/javascript";s.src = "https://portal.form.io/lib/seamless/seamless.parent.min.js";s.onload = function b() {var f = d.getElementById("formio-form-61c559f42d1ebb5cb0058b57");if (!f || (typeof w.seamless === u)) {return setTimeout(b, 100);}w.seamless(f, {fallback:false}).receive(function(d, e) {});};h.appendChild(s);})(document, window);</script><iframe id="formio-form-61c559f42d1ebb5cb0058b57" style="width:100%;border:none;" height="600px" src="https://formview.io/#/bnbozlaqqvhvxka/form1?iframe=1&header=0"></iframe>
```